# How to read a spreadsheet horizontally in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have the following worksheet and I need to read the situation:

- A query that returns me only Alan  PO 129877764 alan@gmail.com
- A query that returns me only Robert QA 119875764 robertqa@gmail.com

One query bringing a record without the code, situation and tab field, and another query bringing all the rows without the code, situation and tab field.

| code | situation | tab | name | job | tel | e-mail |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | Executed | existing hydrometer | Alan | PO | 129877764 | alan@gmail.com |
| 9 | Not Executed | valid reading | Robert | QA | 119875764 | robertqa@gmail.com |

I can't get the values ​​of row 1. If I start the row with 1 I get them all, if I start the row with 2 I get the values ​​of row 2 together with nil. See this image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWgqA.jpg)

```
sheet.each 2 do |row| 
  puts "#{row[3,3]}"
  break if row[1].nil?
 end    
  
 book.io.close
```

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. You may not have known that it's not a good idea to link to images of your code. Here's why: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `each` method is useful if you want to loop over every row in the sheet. If you want to access a single row directly by its index you can do so like you would an array, i.e. with `[]`:

```ruby
row1 = sheet.rows[1]
p row1
# => #<Spreadsheet::Excel::Row:...>
```

Once you have a Row object you can access its fields like you would an array as well, for example to get columns 3–6 (counting from 0):

```ruby
p row1[3..6]
# => ["Alan", "PO", 129877764, "alan@gmail.com"]
```

More succinctly, to get the data you mentioned you could do this:

```ruby
p sheet.rows[1][3..6]
# => ["Alan", "PO", 129877764, "alan@gmail.com"]
p sheet.rows[2][3..6]
# => ["Robert", "QA", 119875764, "robertqa@gmail.com"]
```

Comment: Thank'u.  I have a little difficult validation to do!. It works vertically, but I don't know how to do it horizontally. Can I send you the question or do you prefer that I open a new ticket?

Comment: @SamantaNolasco Best to post a new question. :)

Comment: Friend, I did!.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73778248/validate-excel-correspondence-in-front-end-fields-with-ruby

Comment: OK I understand that this is very difficult for you too. Thank you very much.